# Social media presence

Tags: discussion, twitter

In order to increase the visibility of our site, we may want to start a social media presence. There is now an official **[Twitter feed](http://twitter.com/#!/StackApple)** for questions that people can follow and retweet. I've also set up a **[Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Apple-Stack-Exchange/154758227909964)** for people being able to 'like' the site and share with their friends.

Are there others that would be useful?

Comment: @kylecronin: great idea, but who would administer these feeds/pages?

Comment: @calavera I was thinking the moderators would do it, though they'd probably have to be owned by SO, Inc

Comment: @Dori That's what I was planning on. Any suggestions on the best way to set it up?

Comment: @Dori Thanks, I've set one up [here](http://twitter.com/#!/AppleStackExchg). Looks like it's working OK. Hopefully we can get control over @askdifferent somehow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, we are instituting standard Twitter feeds for all (public) sites; this feed will auto-populate with an interesting question from the site every ~3 hours.

<s>This will be announced next week on the blog with more details so stay tuned</s>

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun a bit then :) - did you grab @askdifferent?

Comment: out of curiosity and without attempting to make you release your super-secret-top-valuable-encrypted algorithm, what constitutes an "interesting question" ?

Comment: @martin it's similar to the http://stackexchange.com hot questions algorithm.. no real secret there .. see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions

Answer (score 1):

This list on wikipedia might be of help to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_networking_websites

Personally I think integration with LinkedIn might be helpful as well - it's nice to let others know that we are sharing our knowledge, and a lot of the people I'm networked with there know a lot about these kind of topics.